# Recreate angular reactive form dynamically when input changes

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a component with reactive form

```
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input('dunamicForm') public: dunamicForm;

  form = new FormGroup({});

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dunamicForm.forEach(x => {
      this.form.addControl(x.id, new FormControl(null));
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
  }
}
```

The problem here is that when `dunamicForm` input changes the `form` remain the same so I came up with this code:

```
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
  @Input('dunamicForm') public: dunamicForm;

  form = new FormGroup({});

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dunamicForm.forEach(x => {
      this.form.addControl(x.id, new FormControl(null));
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({});
    this.dunamicForm.forEach(x => {
      this.form.addControl(x.id, new FormControl(null));
    });
  }
}
```

However it seems didn't help at all as after `ngOnChanges` executed `this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);` does not produce any results.

UPDATE:

I just fixed that this way:

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({});
    this.dunamicForm.forEach(x => {
      this.form.addControl(x.id, new FormControl(null));
    });
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

It is works but I wonder if there a better way because now I have two subscribtions for the same thing.

Comment: The code inside ngAfterViewInit executes after the code inside ngOnInit. So the form is already changed, when you subscribe to changes. Try to put this.form.valueChanges at the very top of ngOnInit.

Comment: @Tortila I found a workaround but wonder if there a better solution, basically need to resubscribe when `this.form` gets a new shape on `ngOnChanges`

Answer (score 0):

why no use a setter in the input?

```
subscription:any; //declare a variable to store the subscription to valueChanges

@Input('dunamicForm') set _dunamicForm(value)
{
  //unsubscribe if you yet subscribe
  if (this.subscription)
  {
     this.subscription.unsubscribe();
     this.subscription=null
  }

  //create a new form
  this.form=new FormGroup({})
  
  value.forEach(x => {
      this.form.addControl(x.id, new FormControl(null));
  });

  //use the variable "subscription" to subscribe
  this.subscription=this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);

}
```

Similar you can do using ngOnChanges